# program crashes while iterating through a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am supposed to create a linked list with the following properties:

```
struct node{
    char *word;
    int times;
    struct node *next;
}head;
```

I have to read each word from a file, check if it exists in the list, and if it doesn't, i should add it. If it already exists i need to increase `times` by one. I use the following code to accomplish that:

```
void append(char *wrd, struct node *start){
    struct node *current = start;

    while(current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(current->word, wrd);
    current->times = 1;
    current->next->next = NULL;

}

int iterate(char *wrd, struct node *start){
    struct node *current = start;

    while(current != NULL){

        if(strcmp(current->word, wrd)==0){
            current->times++;
            return 1;
        }
        current = current->next;

    }

    return 0;
}

void read_file(struct node *start){

    FILE *fp;
    char wrd[20];
    puts("give file name and format(max 19 characters)");
    gets(wrd);

    fp = fopen((const char*)wrd, "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", wrd);
    start->word = malloc(strlen(wrd)+1);
    strcpy(start->word, wrd);

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", wrd) != EOF){

        if(!iterate(wrd, start)){
            append(wrd, start);
        }       

    }

}

void print_data(struct node *start){
    struct node *current = start;
    while(current->next != NULL){
        printf("word: %s , times: %d", current->word, current->times);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct node *start = &head;
    read_file(start);
    return 0;
}
```

`append` takes a word, creates a new node containing it, and adds the node to the list.

`iterate` takes a word and searches the list for a match. If the word already exists within the list, then `times` is increased by one. `0` is returned if no match was found and `1` in the opposite case.

`read_file` initializes the head node, reads the file and calls the above functions for each word it reads.

Let's say i have a text file containing the following words:

```
hello hey world hello
world this is supposed to work
but it does not
```

The program successfuly runs for the first 3 words and creates the nodes. When the match `hello` is found the program crashes. I've determined that the error lies in `iterate`, but i can't figure out what's causing it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you run it under a debugger

Comment: my debugger refuses to work, so i used various `printf` statements and the error is definetely in `iterate`

Comment: allocate for `current->word` before `strcpy(current->word, wrd);`. Also `current->next->word`, `current->next->times = 1;`

Comment: Are you sure your file never contains words longer than 19 characters?

Comment: i ran the program using the file i mentioned above and it crashed just like i described.

Comment: show the definition of head

Comment: u need to get yr debugger working - what platform and how does it 'refuse' to work.

Comment: @pm100 it's just under the definition of the `struct node`

Comment: Aside: after the initial `strcpy(start->word, wrd);` you didn't increment the count: `start->times = 1;`

Comment: @WeatherVane good point

Comment: In `append` when you allocate a new node at the end of the list, instead of working with it you overwrite the data in what was the last node. It is missing `current = current->next;` after the memory allocation.

Comment: You can use `strdup()` instead of `strcpy()` to allocate sufficient space and copy the data in one go.

Comment: In your `append()` function, it looks like you are confused about which node should receive the data.  Without modifying which node `current` points to, you update `*current` with some of the data, and `current->next` with the rest.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah that solved it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yup that was it, thanks!

Comment: And then of course `current->next->next = NULL;` needs to be `current->next = NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, I don't understand why you can confidently say that your program has an error in the `iterate` function.

You haven't allocated any memory to the `word` pointer before `strcpy()`.
I would suggest doing this in your `append()` function:

```
void append(char *wrd, struct node *start){
    struct node *current = start;
    if(current == NULL){
        start = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        start->word = (char *)malloc((strlen(wrd) + 1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(start->word, wrd);
        start->times = 1;
        start->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    while(current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->next->word = (char*)malloc((strlen(wrd) + 1)*sizeof(char)); //add this line
    strcpy(current->next->word, wrd); //not current->word
    current->next->times = 1; //not current->times
    current->next->next = NULL;
}
```

Notice here that in the append function, you did not check if the list is already empty or not. The `if` block is to do the same. Also notice the mistake you made while using `strcpy()`. You wanted to copy the new word in the new pointer, but were doing it in the pointer which is the parent of the new node.

Now, you `read_file()` function will look a lot simpler!

```
 void read_file(struct node *start){

    FILE *fp;
    char wrd[20];
    puts("give file name and format(max 19 characters)");
    gets(wrd);

    fp = fopen((const char*)wrd, "r");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", wrd) != EOF){

        if(!iterate(wrd, start)){
            append(wrd, start);
        }       

    }

}
```

I don't think your `iterate` function needs an update, but `print_data()` surely does:

```
void print_data(struct node *start){
    struct node *current = start;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("word: %s , times: %d", current->word, current->times);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Seems like the only function not having any error was `iterate()`. Happens when you play with pointers! :P